# SQL Group By and Order By with Aggregate Functions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm putting together a Rails app, and I've run into a bit of an SQL snag. While it's solvable in Sqlite3, when I move it to my Heroku server running Postgres, it chokes and dies. The situation is as follows:

```
SPORTS
-----------------------------
|   id    |      title      |
-----------------------------
|   1     |  Baseball       |
-----------------------------

SPORTS_VOTE
------------------------------------
|  id  |   sport_id    |    vote   |
------------------------------------
|  1   |       1       |     1     |
------------------------------------
```

The vote column could be either 1 or -1. I'd like to get a list of the sports ordered by the sum total of the votes. The query I used in Sqlite3 was something like this:

```
  SELECT s.title, sum(sv.vote)
    FROM sports s 
   INNER JOIN sports_vote sv ON s.id = sv.sport_id 
 GROUP BY s.id
 ORDER BY sum(sv.vote);
```

In any respectable DB, this query whines about aggregate functions, etc. What is the best way to do this? Am I better off keeping a 'vote' field in the Sports table, and updating this when votes are cast? The Sports_Vote table also records the ID of the user who submitted the vote, so it's needed.

Secondly, I'd like to ideally combine two similar tables, so that I get a nice list of say, Sports AND Cookies in descending order of votes(Hockey ranked #1, Maple Cookies #2, Football #3, etc). Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule of thumb to prevent errors when using `group by` is:

- **All columns not aggregated must be included in the `group by` clause.**

Therefore, your query should be:

```
 SELECT s.id, s.title, sum(sv.vote)
    FROM sports s 
   INNER JOIN sports_vote sv ON s.id = sv.sport_id 
 GROUP BY s.id, s.title
 ORDER BY sum(sv.vote);
```

OR

```
 SELECT s.title, sum(sv.vote)
    FROM sports s 
   INNER JOIN sports_vote sv ON s.id = sv.sport_id 
 GROUP BY s.title
 ORDER BY sum(sv.vote);
```

To combine with a second table and rank you can just use `union` (the `order by` will apply to the combined result):

```
 SELECT s.title, sum(sv.vote) vote_count
    FROM sports s 
   INNER JOIN sports_vote sv ON s.id = sv.sport_id 
 GROUP BY s.title
 UNION   
 SELECT s.title, sum(sv.vote) vote_count
    FROM cookies s 
   INNER JOIN cookies_vote sv ON s.id = sv.sport_id 
 GROUP BY s.title
 ORDER BY vote_count DESC;
```

About your question on whether you should keep the vote count in the sports table and update when each vote is cast, it depends. Doing so will give you a better performance when generating reports like the above ones (since the `group by` and the `inner join` won't be needed anymore), but it will reduce the performance of casting votes (since now you have to insert AND update a second table). So it depends on your priorities.

Comment: Many thanks, @Diego. This seems to do the trick. One quick follow-up: What is the most elegant way to pull this off in a Rails controller?